# Dynamic require() in pkg (node.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules, require, binaryfiles

**IMPORTANT: If you want to help me or you have the same issue discuss it here:** https://github.com/vercel/pkg/discussions/1580

I'm writing a node.js app which downloads repositories from GitHub at runtime. These contain javascript files which I require at runtime. But now I want to package my code into an executable using [pkg](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pkg), but I read that I can't just simply require packages at runtime using pkg. So my question is: How can I require these files at runtime? I'ts important for me to access its exported function, as I need to pass variables into it. Here is an example dynamically downloaded file:

```js
module.exports = function PluginServerSideRenderer (app, dir, config) {
    /*
     *
     * app is the express app
     * dir is the current-working-directory of the server or mostly the root
     * config is the config.json file as a javascript object
     * 
     */

    app.get('/__plugin-template__', (req, res) => {
        // Uncomment if user must be logged in to access this page
        // if (req.session.loggedin !== true) return res.redirect('/login') // Login Check
        res.send('Hello World from the Plugin-Template!')
    })
}
```

Normally I would use this code to import these files:

```js
// Plugin Server Side Renderer
const plugindirx = path.join(dir, '.tvt', 'plugins')
const files = fs.readdirSync(plugindirx)
const activeplugins = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(path.join(plugindirx, 'active.json'), 'utf8').toString())

for (const plugindiroutoffiles of files) {
   if (plugindiroutoffiles === 'active.json') continue
   if (!(activeplugins[genFileName(plugindiroutoffiles)])) continue

   const filesx = fs.readdirSync(path.join(plugindirx, plugindiroutoffiles))
   const ssrfile = path.join(plugindirx, plugindiroutoffiles, filesx[0], 'serverside.js')

   require(ssrfile)(app, dir, config, Logger, IServConfig)
}
// End Plugin Server Side Renderer
```

Comment: That sounds incredibly insecure: how does your code guarantee that the additional code it's downloading is actually the original files, and not something with exploits injected into it? Unless you're doing something _highly_ unusual, just define your dependencies in package.json, install them, and then use those. Especially if you're trying to create a standalone package, just get your dependencies first, and package them into your release. The security issues from trying to get more code from github at runtime aren't worth the few mb you're saving by not getting them at build time.

Comment: I hope it does that over SSL and secured behind an auth token. Assuming it does: the link for `pkg` in your post does not go to https://www.npmjs.com/package/pkg, so are you using `pkg`, or are you using `ffbinaries`, which is what your link points to? And if it's `pkg`: you probably want to _start_ by asking this over on https://github.com/vercel/pkg/discussions rather than here (because if this is a usecase not covered by the docs, that will let the pkg folks update the documentation so that _everyone_ wins, not just people who find your question on SO =)

Comment: Oh sorry wrong link, I meant https://www.npmjs.com/package/pkg

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Also, I started a discussion here: https://github.com/vercel/pkg/discussions/1580

Comment: no news? still didnt work even with require-runtime

Comment: @AbdennourTOUMI It kinda worked, but it wasn't perfect. Also my use had a too high security risk, so I moved away from this method and am spawning seperaten processes that interact over stout/in.